# Create a .jks file from a Certificate and private Key

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, pkcs#11

I wanted to create a .jks file using a Certificate and a private Key from an etoken programmatically.
I could access the etoken using the password but could not read the Certificate or the private key.
In an earlier question I had asked whether the private Key could be extracted from the etoken for which I was told it was not possible.
So, my question is whether I could get the reference of the private key using PKCS11..
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the reference (object handle) of the PrivateKey using PKCS11. You can even get the public components of the PrivateKey. But you cannot extract the sensitive data that comprises the key.